# Phantom \.txt file in windows

Tags: c++, windows

It seems like it is possible to create a file `\.txt` in windows that can be read, but I'm not able to access it any other way or see if it exists. This seems to only work for `\.txt` since I can't create other files with backslashes in it such as `a\.txt`

```
string filename = "\\.txt";

// make file
ofstream writer(filename);
writer << "This file exists" << endl;
writer.close();

// read file
ifstream reader(filename);
string line;
getline(reader, line);
cout << line << endl;
reader.close();
```

When I use `ls -lia` in bash, this file doesn't show up at all, but the program above reads it fine (I can remove the part that creates the file and run it later so the file does persists), how does this work?

Comment: "_fles with backslashes in_" - No files have backslashes in their filenames in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, `ofstream writer("\\.txt")` creates a file named `.txt` in the root of the current drive. It is a perfectly valid file name.

`ofstream writer("a\\.txt")` tries to create a file named `.txt` in the `a` subdirectory of the current directory. The `a` directory must exist in order for it to succeed. Most likely it does not exist, therefore it fails for you.

To create a directory you can use either the `mkdir` function (which has compatibility problems with other OSes because Windows is not POSIX compatible), or the `CreateDirectory` WINAPI function, that is Windows specific. After calling `CreateDirectoryA("a")`, the `"a\\.txt"` path should work.

Comment: An alternative to the platform specific versions to create a directory would be to use the standard [`std::filesystem::create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) function (if C++17 or later can be used).